# Атомарные переменные в си

Tags: c, многопоточность

Пишу под микроконтроллер в первый раз и так и не нагуглил такой вопрос.

Например, понятно что доступ к `int_32` может быть атомарным на 32 битной машине, но на 16 битной скорее всего уже будет не атомарным. Но логика подсказывает, что меньше байта считать точно нельзя (по крайней мере я о таком никогда не слышал) и в теории `volatile char` может обеспечить эту самую атомарность.

Так ли это? Конечно я понимаю, что стандарт си ничего не говорит за это и в теории может быть какой нибудь 4х битный процессор, в котором даже char не атомарен. Но на практике, могу ли я использовать `char` в качестве, скажем, флага синхронизации между прерыванием и функции main?

Comment: `volatile char` -- можете. Лучше static (или extern. Впрочем, это один и тот же класс памяти, только области видимости разные).

Comment: Атомарность с размером слова ни как не связана. Например на x86 даже обычный инкремент `++i;` не атомарен. И абсолютно не важно, что там, `char` или `long long`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, разве неатомарен? Точно не путаешь с шарпом или джавой?

Comment: @Qwertiy, `inc <mem>` — не атомарен, но немного в другом смысле, нежели это подразумевается на контроллерах: результаты обработки прерывания в однопроцессорной системе он не изменит, а вот в многопроцессорной потоки будут соревноваться за адрес и некоторые обновления могут пропускаться... Конечно если речь идёт об обычном адресе в обычной памяти, если это адрес из памяти какого-нибудь устройства, то даже на однопроцессорной системе он не атомарен...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Небольшое замечание. Инкремент действительно не обязательно атомарен. Он без проблем может быть разделен на операции чтения, сложения и записи в память (зависит от процессора.и компилятора). А вот атомарность записи/чтения связана с размером слова + процессором (даже скорее с разрядностью процессора или даже разрядностью конкретной команды) - одни команды могут быть записаны за один такт, другие за несколько.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт Си ни о какой атомарности ничего не знает, `volatile` [не про это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c), тут же вам не Ява какая-нибудь. Все что вы описали это строго аппаратно зависимые вещи. Более того, нередко производитель вычислителя еще и свой компилятор поставляет, который тоже свою специфику и отклонения имеет. Все подобные вопросы только к производителю.

Вообще, аппаратная кроссплатформа это одна сплошная боль, более разумно писать отдельно под каждый камень.

Comment: кстати, стандарт С11 знает такой хедр как [`<stdatomic.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). Для справедливости стоит упомянуть, что его статус всё же «опциональное расширение».